# Kotlin Quarkus Avro NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus, avro

I have created an application that reads data from a Kafka topic using Quarkus and Kotlin. The data on the topic are in Avro format, so I have to use `io.quarkus:quarkus-avro` dependency.

Everything works fine but when I set Quarkus log level to `DEBUG` or higher I get the following message.

```
DEBUG requestId= traceId=, spanId=, sampled= [io.quarkus.deployment.util.FSWatchUtil] (FSWatchUtil) Failed checking for code gen source modifications: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: <projectfolder>/build/classes/java/quarkus-generated-sources/avro
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:220)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:277)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:323)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:71)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3918)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3973)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.util.FSWatchUtil.doObserve(FSWatchUtil.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.util.FSWatchUtil.lambda$observe$1(FSWatchUtil.java:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The path is related to Java but I have only Kotlin code so I didn't find a way to suppress the error.